# Retrieving multiple post variables in a controller function in Codeingiter

Tags: ajax, controller

I am posting data to controller like this:

```
var postVars = new Array();
postVars[0] = key;
postVars[1] = haveCredits;
postVars[2] = creditsNeeded;
postVars[3] = creditsLeft;
//alert(postVars.join("&"));
xhr.open('POST', 'ajax');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(postVars.join("&"));
```

How can i retrieve this values in my controller function?

Controller code:

```
$variableValues= explode('&',$this->input->post('postVars'));
```

It is returning an empty array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change last row like this:

```
xhr.send("postVars="+encodeURIComponent(postVars.join("&")));
```

Now `$variableValues= explode('&',$this->input->post('postVars'));` should work.

Btw, i would like to introduce you to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It's one of the most popular JavaScript libraries and has very powerfull [AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

What you're sending isn't really `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. You're just joining together string values, rather than named, URL-escaped parameters.

I suggest sending separate parameters in standard URL-encoded format:

```
function encodeParameters(o) {
    for (var k in o)
        pars.push(encodeURIComponent(k)+'='+encodeURIComponent(o[k]))
    return pars.join('&');
}

var pars= {key: key, have: haveCredits, needed: creditsNeeded, left: creditsLeft};
xhr.open('POST', '/ajax');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(encodeParameters(pars));
```

then on the PHP side you can retrieve them using the normal request arrays:

```
$key= $_POST['key'];
$creditsNeeded= intval($_POST['needed']);
// ...
```